# Resource Drawable Not Found

Tags: java, android

When I install my application on my phone, it immediately crashes telling me the drawable is not found:

```
Resource "com.aaronapp.hideme:drawable/ic_clear" (7f07007a)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07007a a=-1 r=0x7f07007a}
```

Here is where it is not finding this drawable:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/clear_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clear"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    app:fabSize="mini" />
```

And here is a screenshot of the ic_clear.xml file that is in the drawable that I am trying to refer to, but it's throwing the error:

[image]

What is the issue here? I clearly have ic_clear.xml in my drawable folder... 
thanks for the help!

Comment: is it a vector drawable?

Comment: yes it is a vector drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your resources are located in `drawable-v24` (this is for the android version 24 and above) folder, just relocate all your resources to `drawable` forlder and it should work